# Assistance with passing multiple objects via a list to Jsonresponse in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a code in Django where 5 random numbers are selected and then based on those 5 numbers 5 more queries are made from the database. One this is done I would like to pass all 5 objects from database to the template via json., however I am not sure how to proceed with this. This is what I have now:

```
class multiplePull(TemplateView):
template_name = 'gacha/multiplePull.html'

def randomStar(self):
    choice = [5,4,3]
    probability = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]
    star = random.choices(choice, probability)
    return star[0]

def post(self, request):
    multi = []
    characters = []
    for x in range(5):
        star = self.randomStar()
        multi.append(star)

    for star in multi:
        character = Characters.objects.filter(stars=star).order_by('?')[:1]
        for obj in character:
            characters.append(obj)

    return JsonResponse(json.dumps(characters), safe=False)
```

As it is now I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'QuerySet' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I do this to make it work? I think I am missing something still but can't really find a solution. This works fine when I simply send this as context data but I don't know how to pass all 5 objects via Json. I would appreciate all help.

Thanks you.

Comment: for most easiest way.. use rest framework. and for your error it's exactly what it says. if you want to dump it into json you can not directly dump queryset directly to json hence you need to convert queryset in to json serializable object in either dictionary, string or list

Comment: So I'm going in the right direction, just need to serialise the data, yes?

Comment: if you mean "5 random numbers are selected" with user input with post method from template then yes. but it doesn't fit for what you are using post method? you are not using any post data in the code you have posted

Comment: I still don't understand. I managed to pass a list of items via json(only random numbers now). How do I iterate through them after they've been passed? I guess I need to use jquery for this, yes?

Comment: be precise in question about what your motive is, what you are doing in template and how, and what you are doing in view, and what is your expectation from code

Comment: Ok, I will need to re-think this through again. If anything I will post a new question with all included. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code, is that the queryset (and the objects of you model that are contained in it) is not automatically serializable to JSON.

You will have to find a way to do that job. For example, [like DRF uses serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

If you think that is too much work for your use-case, you can make your code work by transforming your `QuerySet` into a list (`list(characters)`) and then each element in it, into a dictionary containing the fields you desire to include in the response.

Comment: So I would need to transform every obj into a list then? Let me try this.

Comment: Not to a list but to a dictionary in order to be automatically serializable to a JSON object.